# Can I develop an application on Windows intending to deploy it to OSX?

Tags: mono, cross-platform, monodevelop

I'm looking to create an application that will be executed on a Mac machine, but I don't have one to develop on.  I thought this would be a great opportunity to try and take advantage of the Mono runtime.  I'm trying to figure out how to develop on a Windows XP machine and prepare a deployment package for an OSX machine.

I'd like to try and make the application have a UI since my users are not very technical.  Is MonoDevelop the right tool to accomplish this?  Should I be trying to use Windows Forms or GTK#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep , you should use mono on windows directly with GTK# , but you'll need a few tweaks on mac so you'll need a mac eventualy. Your users will have to install the mono framework on their computer too, mono doesnt produce native Mac applications.
I love mono but if the end users are not very technical I dont think it is the right solution.
Anyway , the only way to develop some real multiplatform apps is Java, since it is pre installed on Macs so users will not have to download a framework to launch your apps.

Comment: Bummer.  I was hoping to be able to use this as an opportunity to get to work with Mono.  I was aware of Java as an option, but like I said, I was looking for a learning opportunity as well.

Comment: You can create the app bundle as described in jpobst's answer without needing a Mac, and the bundle will prompt the user to install Mono.

Comment: You can also include Mono in the app bundle, so the user doesn't need to install it, but you would need a Mac to do this.